# ¿Cómo retornar recursivamente los elementos de una Lista utilizando el método Divide y Vencerás?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, recursión

Necesito saber como obtener los elementos de la Lista L, con una función que vaya dividiendo la lista en 2 y finalmente retorne los elementos en orden,

No sirve la función, pero es el Ejemplo:

```
L = [[3, 8], [0, 4], [5, 8], [2, 6], [1, 4], [4, 9], [0, 5], [1, 1], [2, 8], [1, 7]]
```

```
def Funcion1(Lista, ini, fin):
  if (ini == fin):
      return Lista[ini]
  else:
      mid = (ini + fin) // 2    
      return Funcion1(Lista, ini, mid) , Funcion1(Lista, mid+1, fin)
```

**output:** No necesito mostrarlo en consola, es para entender el formato del `return Funcion1()`

```
>>> [3, 8]
>>> [0, 4]
>>> [5, 8]
>>>  ...
```

Cada vez que `Funcion1(L, ini, fin):` me retorne los valores `[a, b]`, llamare otra función `Funcion2(a, b)` Que utilizara estos valores cada vez que `Funcion1` los retorne.

Y ¿Cómo debo implementar La `Funcion2(a, b)` dentro de `Funcion1(L, ini, fin)` para utilizar los valores `[a, b]`?

[image: Imagen referencia]

Comment: Pues nada, que nos volvemos a encontrar. Esta vez ya con el esquema, es un poco más entendible lo que quieres y he reproducido [un miniprograma](https://www.online-python.com/F8AZgiqGlT) justo con tu esquema y lo que pretendes. Aún así, no creo que tengas claro que una función te devuelve una sola cosa, no "muchas", pero bueno, al menos tu pregunta se entiende mejor. ¡Saludos de nuevo!

Comment: Muchas gracias Jaime, esta vez seguí tu recomendación sobre el post de la pregunta y esta segunda solución que me das, es lo que necesitaba, gracias.

Comment: yo le pondria a ese `print` un `print(Lista[0], end='')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu esquema ilustra perfectamente el algoritmo a seguir. Tienes una lista de entrada `L`, que vas a ir dividiendo recursivamente hasta que tengas un solo elemento. Cuando tengas un solo elemento, haces lo que sea que necesites (en este caso yo llamé a la función `print`):

```
L = [[3, 8], [0, 4], [5, 8], [2, 6], [1, 4], [4, 9], [0, 5], [1, 1], [2, 8], [1, 7], [0, 8]]


def Funcion1(Lista):
    if len(Lista) <= 1:
        # Aqui llamas a la otra funcion, en este caso, yo llamo a print
        print(Lista[0])
    else:
        mid = len(Lista) // 2
        Funcion1(Lista[0:mid])
        Funcion1(Lista[mid:])


Funcion1(L)
```

Puedes ejecutar el programa desde tu navegador en [este enlace](https://www.online-python.com/F8AZgiqGlT). La salida es:

```
[3, 8]
[0, 4]
[5, 8]
[2, 6]
[1, 4]
[4, 9]
[0, 5]
[1, 1]
[2, 8]
[1, 7]
[0, 8]
```